# jquery function works in one page but not in other with same attributes (but it works on the console)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Im in a really weird situation here. Im trying to hide two elements with jquery in wordpress woocommerce checkout page. It is something like this (pseudo code):

```
if (#id) is >= 1 
    then hide (elements)
else
    show (elements)
```

and my code is thisone:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    if (jQuery('#shipping_method_0_free_shipping6').length >= 1 ) { 
        jQuery('[for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate8"]').hide();
        jQuery('[value="flat_rate:8"]').hide();
    } else { 
        jQuery( "#shipping_method_0_flat_rate8" ).show() && jQuery(".woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").show(); 
}
});
```

The weird thing is that this is working good on "cart" page on woocommerce if I add the script on a code block but when I add it on "checkout" page, works while the page is loading but as soon the page is fully loaded, the elements shows again... Some ideas why or some sugestions?

Thanks a lot for taking time to take a look!

Comment: Btw, if I execute the code on the console it works... :/

Comment: There is probably some code running on the page, after yours, which is reversing your changes... without seeing the whole page it's impossible to guess

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Hi Darren! You can take a look here: http://shop.hvskok.com/checkout/ (when the price is more than 2000kr (swedish kr) the 59kr radio button should disappear, just like in: http://shop.hvskok.com/cart-2/)

Comment: Both of the pages show nothing to me - you need to reproduce the problem in a fiddle or something similar so we can help debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WooCommerce the checkout is generated by Ajax. So when the page loads, the checkout is generated like every other element, then the document ready event fires, then WooCommerce reloads the checkout with ajax. So basically your jQuery code is only applying to the first load of the checkout, which is immediately overwritten by the Ajax.

To solve this you can run a function on the updated_checkout event, which WooCommerce adds. Like this:

```
jQuery('body').on('updated_checkout', function() {
     if (jQuery('#shipping_method_0_free_shipping6').length >= 1 ) { 
         jQuery('[for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate8"]').hide();
         jQuery('[value="flat_rate:8"]').hide();
     } else { 
         jQuery( "#shipping_method_0_flat_rate8" ).show() && jQuery(".woocommerce-Price-amount.amount").show(); 
     }
}
```